# So what are state space representations actually doing? How are the state vectors related to the output?

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

I'm currently learning state space representations but I am really struggling with the concept. More specifically, I'm not seeing how the selection of state variables is made based off of an output and how the state variables are even related to begin with.

What exactly is our state vector equation **doing** and how is this related to the output?

$$
\dot{x} = A\,x + B\,u \\
y = C\,x + D\,u
$$

Comment: It is basically just a systematic way to write down a set of differential equations (in your case, linear differential equations). How these equations/state variables are related to each other depends on the context, i.e. on the relationship that is described by these equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to look at a simple example like a mass-spring-damper system with an external force $u$. The equation of motion is given by

$$m\ddot{x}+b\dot{x}+cx = u$$

Now, we want to translate this system into the state-space-representation by introducing the following substitutions $x = x_1$ and $\dot{x}=\dot{x}_1=x_2$. Note that this transformation is not unique. You could also choose $x=2x_1$. Using these substitutions we can write the equation of motion as

$$m\dot{x}_2+bx_2+cx_1=u.$$
Solving for $\dot{x}_2$ results in

$$\dot{x}_2 = -\dfrac c m x_1 - \dfrac b m x_2 +\dfrac{1}{m}u$$

Combining this equation with $\dot{x}_1=x_2$ results in a system of equations

$$\dot{x}_1=x_2$$
$$\dot{x}_2 = -\dfrac c m x_1 - \dfrac b m x_2 +\dfrac{1}{m}u$$

or in matrix representation using $\boldsymbol{x}=[x_1,x_2]^T$

$$\dot{\boldsymbol{x}}=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\ -c/m & b/m \end{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{x} + \begin{bmatrix}0\\1/m \end{bmatrix}u.$$

The matrices in front of the state vector $\boldsymbol{x}$ and the control input vector $u$ are the $\boldsymbol{A}$ and $\boldsymbol{B}$ matrices. I hope this explains the system equation. The system equation describes the dynamics of the system given your control input.

In contrast to this, the output equation describes the measurement design of the system. Hence, it describes what you measure from the system. For example, if you say that you only measure the velocity of the mass then the output equation is given by

$$y=\dot{x}=x_2=[0,\,1]\boldsymbol{x}+[0]u.$$

If you measure other things you will get other output equations.

Comment: The main "problem" of state space models is that you can always apply a [similarity transformation](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Representations/SysRepTransformations/SS2SS.html), while still having the same input output relation. So there is no one correct or neccesarally more correct choice for the state vector from a mathmatical perspective. But from a numerical perspective it can make a difference, namely the Matlab function [balreal](https://se.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/balreal.html) should behave better numerically compared to for example the controllable canonical form.

Comment: Brilliant. I see the use of it more clearly now. I'll be doing this in MATlab to get a better feel for it but it seems very powerful with a spring mass system. I took an analysis class that required is to find solutions to spring systems using the normal way of solving for ODE's. Our prof recently went over this example and its quite clear why this is so useful. Thank you.